# Android Studio: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

** Hi, I would like to display the elements of a sqlite table on the historic page (fragment_historic). I recuperate well the elements in BD but the elements are not recovered in

`ViewHolder.trxId.setText (trx.getTransaction_id ()); 
ViewHolder.amount.setText (trx.getTransaction_amount (). ToString ());         ViewHolder.dateTime.setText (trx.getTransaction_DateTime ());           ViewHolder.cardNumber.setText (trx.getTransaction_cardNumber ());`

** TransactionAdapter class **

```
  public class TransactionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction>
    {
        ImageView downloadImageButton;
        public TransactionAdapter(Context context, List<Transaction> trx)
        {
            super(context, 0, trx);
        }

        @Override
        public View  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_historic, parent, false);
            }

            TransactionViewHolder viewHolder = (TransactionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            if (viewHolder == null)
            {
                viewHolder = new TransactionViewHolder();

                viewHolder.dateTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_dt);
                viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_amount);
                viewHolder.trxId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_id);
                viewHolder.cardNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_cn);
               viewHolder.statusImgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_status);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            //getItem(position) va récupérer l'item [position] de la List<Tweet> tweets
            Transaction trx = getItem(position);

            System.out.println("TEST..............................position " + position + "amount : " + trx.getTransaction_amount().toString() + "dateTime : " + trx.getTransaction_DateTime() + "cardNumber" + trx.getTransaction_cardNumber());

            //il ne reste plus qu'à remplir notre vue
            viewHolder.trxId.setText(trx.getTransaction_id());
            viewHolder.amount.setText(trx.getTransaction_amount().toString());
            viewHolder.dateTime.setText(trx.getTransaction_DateTime());
            viewHolder.cardNumber.setText(trx.getTransaction_cardNumber());

            if (trx.getTransaction_status() == "APPROVED")
            {
                downloadImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trx_status_ok);
            } else
            {
                downloadImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trx_status_nok);
            }
            viewHolder.statusImgView=downloadImageButton;


            return convertView;

        }

        class TransactionViewHolder
        {
            public TextView dateTime;
            public TextView trxId;
            public TextView amount;
            public TextView cardNumber;
           public ImageView statusImgView;
            public TextView status;

        }
    }


    public class HistoricFragment extends Fragment
    {


        PaymentAppDbHelper db;
        ListView mListView;
        List<Transaction> trx;
    //    View cellule = new View(getContext());

       // Button btn_back_diagonistics;
        private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            fragmentActivity=(FragmentActivity) activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }



        public HistoricFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_historic, container, false);
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


            mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewTest);
            db= new PaymentAppDbHelper(getContext());

            try
            {

                trx = db.SelectTransactions();

            } catch (ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            TransactionAdapter adapter = new TransactionAdapter(getContext(), trx);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {

            }

            setRetainInstance(true);



        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                //Restore the fragment's state here
            }
        }

        @Override`enter code here`
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);




        }
    }


    <!--fragment_historic-->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/noir"
        tools:context="com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.fragments.HistoricFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:id="@+id/ll_cel_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tablerow_white_bg">

            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_dateTime"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_dateTime"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_trxID"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trxID"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_cardNum"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_cardNum"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_amount"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="STATUS"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_status"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--_______________________-->
        <!--transactions à afficher-->
        <!--_______________________-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ll_cel_one"
            android:tag="ll_row_entries"
            android:background="@drawable/tablerow_grey_bg"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_cel_title"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12:04 AM\nNov 16"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trx2_dt"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123456"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trx2_id"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="425698******1234"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trx2_cn"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
            <com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.utils.fonts.SourceSansProBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15.75"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trx2_amount"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trx2_status"
                android:src="@drawable/trx_status_ok"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Modifier_historic"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonback_new" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>





    <!--activity_main-->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:padding="0dp">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/noir"/>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/displayedTextView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

    //Error

    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo, PID: 10395
                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                          at com.alcineo.demo.androiddemo.fragments.HistoricFragment.onViewCreated(HistoricFragment.java:121)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5683)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Comment: `mListView` is null in `onViewCreated()`. You're looking for it in the `Fragment`'s layout - `fragment_historic` - which you did inflate in `onCreateView()`, but it's not in that layout. You have it in the `Activity`'s layout, `activity_main`. If you want the `ListView` in the `Fragment`, move it to the `Fragment`'s layout.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to bind data of `trx` to your adapter, however `trx` has no data and that is why you got null pointer exception. I think, you should check `PaymentAppDbHelper` class. Since you did not provide information about `PaymentAppDbHelper` class, I could not tell you what is the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, PaymentAppDbHelper allows me to instantiate the SelectTransactions method. And I have 30 trx selected in database. However, the problem is in the TransactionAdapter class when calling the setText.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi i have slight change your code try it**
Hope its help!

```
@Override
public View  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    TransactionViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    // check View is null or not
    if (convertView == null){

        //inflating view in convertView object
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_historic, parent, false);
        //creating instance of TransactionViewHolder
        viewHolder = new TransactionViewHolder();

        //binding ids to views
        viewHolder.dateTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_dt);
        viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_amount);
        viewHolder.trxId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_id);
        viewHolder.cardNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_cn);
        viewHolder.statusImgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trx2_status);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (TransactionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //getItem(position) va récupérer l'item [position] de la List<Tweet> tweets
    Transaction trx = getItem(position);

    System.out.println("TEST..............................position " + position + "amount : " + trx.getTransaction_amount().toString() + "dateTime : " + trx.getTransaction_DateTime() + "cardNumber" + trx.getTransaction_cardNumber());

    //il ne reste plus qu'à remplir notre vue
    viewHolder.trxId.setText(trx.getTransaction_id());
    viewHolder.amount.setText(trx.getTransaction_amount().toString());
    viewHolder.dateTime.setText(trx.getTransaction_DateTime());
    viewHolder.cardNumber.setText(trx.getTransaction_cardNumber());

    if (trx.getTransaction_status() == "APPROVED"){
        downloadImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trx_status_ok);
    } else{
        downloadImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trx_status_nok);
    }
    viewHolder.statusImgView=downloadImageButton;
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I tried but I always have the same error while trx is not empty

Comment: Use BaseAdapter, or post complete Activity, Transaction.class and SampleData for showing on List